# Не скрывается папка

Tags: c#

Если папки нет, то создать скрытую не получается, если же папка существует, она скрывается!

Как скрыть папку при создание?

```
public static void CheckSleep(int Attrb)
{
    Thread.Sleep(Attrb);
}
public static void DirDeleteEx(string DirEx,bool TruBoo)
{
    Directory.Delete(DirEx, TruBoo);
}
private static DirectoryInfo DirCreate(string FldPath)
{
    return Directory.CreateDirectory(FldPath);
}
private static bool DirExistsEx(string FldPathEx)
{
    return Directory.Exists(FldPathEx);
}
public static void Toggle()
{
    if (DirExistsEx(str0)) 
        {
            DirDeleteEx(MainFolder, true); // удаляю папку перед созданием
            CheckSleep(1000); // засыпаем на секунду

            var di = DirCreate(MainFolder); // скорее всего из-за этого..
            di.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden; // скрываю папку

            if (!di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)) // если папка скрыта
            {
                DirCreate(MainFolder); // создаю папку
                if (DirExistsEx(str1))
                    DirCreate(str1);
            }
        }
}
```

**Требуется:**

*1) - Удалить папку перед созданием.*

*2) - Скрыть папку которую создаём.*

*3) - Проверить папку что она скрылась, и создать доп папки.*

Comment: Как проверить что папка скрытая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Узнать скрытый или не скрытый файл или папка

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo("путь");
if (d.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
{
     //код
     //создать доп папки.
}
```